# Joining 4 tables SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to join four tables. My query doesn't seem to work though. What I want to do is find all the email addresses for people who rented before 2016. Our database structure is modified so I need to join the table packages. I want the following columns to be output:

- user_id
- activities
- email

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
u.id,
activities,
Max(DATE_PART('year', b.created_at)),
u.email
FROM boats bts
INNER JOIN packages p ON p.boat_id = bts.id
INNER JOIN bookings b ON b.package_id = p.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.booking_id = b.id
WHERE b.created_at BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2015-12-30'
GROUP BY u.id, activities
LIMIT 100;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: INNER JOIN users u ON p.boat_id = bts.id ... this line looks problematic.. are they joining ON the right columns?  Also what's the table structure and what's the current output of urs?

Comment: Please explain `query doesn't seem to work` in more details. What db structure, what output you get and what output is expected

Comment: Users table is not mapped to other table. so you will not get proper result. Share DB structure of all 4 tables.

Comment: I am not sure how I access the DB structure. I am a newbie

Comment: Error message says: `ERROR: column u.booking_id does not exist`

Comment: Click on Object Explorer ->Expand Databases->Expand your database->Expand Database Diagrams. You can get DB Structure.

Comment: What is "activities"? What table does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a wrong join

```
INNER JOIN users u ON u.booking_id = b.id
```

Does really your users table have a foreign key to bookings? Normally it would be the outher way around I guess.

```
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id= b.user_id
```

Is my guess

Best

Peter

Comment: Can you provide a script for the 4 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the statement :-

INNER JOIN users u ON p.boat_id = bts.id

In your query .  A join with the users table should include a column from the table in the join statement

Answer (score 0):

Try with

Click on Object Explorer ->Expand Databases->Expand your database->Expand Database Diagrams. You can get DB Structure.

Right Click on the Table in Object Explorer->Script Table as->Create To->New Query Editor Window, will give you the create table query and check the datatypes of the columns you are joining both data types should be same and the fields should be there in the relevant table as well

If you need only the matching record, then you can continue with inner join, But if you need non matching records as well go with left or right join accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
u.id,
activities,
Max(DATE_PART('year', b.created_at)),
u.email
FROM boats bts
INNER JOIN packages p ON p.boat_id = bts.id
INNER JOIN bookings b ON b.package_id = p.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.created_at BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2015-12-30'
GROUP BY u.id, activities, u.email
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to group by **u.email** as well.

Best regards
Peter